# Get getNotifyStockQty() using `product_id`

Tags: magento-1.9, sql

I want to run below sql from a observer

`select notify_stock_qty from cataloginventory_stock_item where product_id= 119`

How to do this in Magento way.

```
$product_id= 119;
$stock_qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventorystock/item')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId);
```

Comment: If the answer will help you then mark it as accepted. so it will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$product_id= 119;

$stock_qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product_id)->getNotifyStockQty();
```

To fetch the quantity (in stock) for any given product

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
$_product = $model->load($product_id); 
$stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                ->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
```

Comment: let me try this one

Comment: @Nilkunj it works , it gave the desired output

Comment: can you plz tell me the what to pass in getModel to get current stock using product id

Comment: i am trying this `$stock_qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product_id)->getQty();`

Comment: $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product_id);

echo $stock->getQty();
echo $stock->getMinQty();
echo $stock->getMinSaleQty();

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank You sir, can you please share any helpful article from where i can understand table structure in getModel()

Comment: you should check this: https://www.pierrefay.com/magento-training/model-database-tutorial.html